# Getstatic in jvm

Tags: jvm

`getstatic` has the following form: `getstatic <spec-field> <descriptor>`
And `spec-field` is just "address" a field we want. But, why a `descriptor` is needed?

Answer (score 0):

- JVM Specification, unlike Java Language Specification, allows a class to have multiple fields with the same name, but with different types (descriptors).
- Java is statically typed, so `getfield`/`getstatic` bytecodes should somehow specify the type of a field they deal with. Since fields are identified by name-and-type pair, the type becomes unambiguous. Otherwise different bytecodes would be required for different field types.
- Consider a class `A` that refers to the field `f` in class `B`. The way to address fields by their name and descriptor solves a number of problems when the type of `f` changes, and the class `B` is recompiled independently of `A`.

Comment: In principle, the type of the field could be inferred without the need to introduce new byte code. But this implies that to verify code containing a field access, the owner class of the field had to be loaded, to get the field’s type. The way it is now, the correctness of the code can be verified prior to linkage.